# Build function to clear field and send_keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I'm trying build a function to clear a field and send_keys, but I'm getting error. See my code:

**base.py**

```
class Page(object):

    def clear_sendkeys(self, *locator, text):

        self.driver.find_element(*locator).clear()
        self.driver.find_element(*locator).send_keys(text)
```

**contractors_page.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from base import Page
from locators import *
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from faker import Faker
import os
import time

def update_contacts_form(self):

    enter_building = fake.building_number()

    self.clear_sendkeys(*ContractorsLocators.EMAIL, enter_building)
```

**My error**

> E       self.clear_sendkeys(*ContractorsLocators.EMAIL, enter_building)
>   E   SyntaxError: only named arguments may follow *expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant have fixed argument after variable argument which means 
`def clear_sendkeys(self, *locator, text)` is wrong it should be 
`def clear_sendkeys(self, text, *locator)`.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve your issue, you can change the order of your function arguments as follows:

```
def clear_sendkeys(self, text, *locator):
    self.driver.find_element(*locator).clear()
    self.driver.find_element(*locator).send_keys(text)
```

And call it like:

```
self.clear_sendkeys(enter_building, *ContractorsLocators.EMAIL)
```

Answer (score 0):

the method is defined like this: `def clear_sendkeys(self, *locator, text):`

`*locator` grabs positional arguments. So when calling your method, you cannot pass more positional arguments after your first argument.

Just pass the last argument as a keyword/named argument (using `text=` prefix) as the error message suggests:

```
self.clear_sendkeys(*ContractorsLocators.EMAIL, text=enter_building)
```

Comment: Now return syntax error: `E       def clear_sendkeys(self, *locator, text):
E                                             ^
E   SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: `E def clear_sendkeys(self, *locator, text):`. You've got an `E` just before your function. I'm certainly not responsible for that.